# What to do when we get an 'X' in the output in Array Multiplier code in structural style while displaying output?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Here's my code :
(I was trying to make a simple 4x4 Array Multiplier)

I have defined a Full Adder,
and then I have defined a Basic block, which consists of a full adder and and an `and` gate.

Code Body :

```
// MODULE
//Set the measurement and percesion of time
`timescale 1ns / 1ps         

//Create a module for Full Adder and define all the inputs, outputs and wires involved
module FA_struct(a, b, c_in, sum, c_out);
    input a, b, c_in;
    output sum, c_out;
    
    wire w1,w2,w3;
    
    xor (w1, a, b);
    xor (sum, w1, c_in);
    
    and (w2, a, b);
    and (w3, w1, c_in);
    
    or (c_out, w3, w2);
endmodule

//Basic Block structure
module BB_struct(a, b, pp, c_in, sum, c_out);
    input a, b, pp, c_in;
    output sum, c_out;
    
    wire w1;
    and (w1, a, b);
    
    FA_struct basic_block(w1, pp, c_in, sum, c_out);
endmodule


module array_multiplier(A, B, prod);
    input[3:0] A, B;
    output[7:0] prod;
    
    wire[3:0] c0, c1, c2, c3;
    
    wire[3:0] s0, s1, s2;
    
    assign a = 0;
    
    BB_struct l00 (A[0], B[0], a, a, prod[0], c0[0]);
    
    BB_struct l01 (A[1], B[0], a, a, s0[1], c0[1]);
    BB_struct l10 (A[0], B[1], s0[1], a, prod[1], c1[0]);
    
    BB_struct l02 (A[2], B[0], a, a, s0[2], c0[2]);
    BB_struct l11 (A[1], B[1], s0[2], c1[0], s1[1], c1[1]);
    BB_struct l20 (A[0], B[2], s1[1], a, prod[2], c2[0]);
    
    BB_struct l03 (A[3], B[0], a, a, s0[3], c0[3]);
    BB_struct l12 (A[2], B[1], s0[3], c1[1], s1[2], c1[2]);
    BB_struct l21 (A[1], B[2], s1[2], c2[0], s2[1], c2[1]);
    BB_struct l30 (A[0], B[3], s2[1], a, prod[3], c3[0]);
    
    BB_struct l13 (A[3], B[1], a, c1[2], s1[3], c1[3]);
    BB_struct l22 (A[2], B[2], s1[3], c2[1], s2[2], c2[3]);
    BB_struct l31 (A[1], B[3], s2[2], c3[0], prod[4], c3[1]);
    
    BB_struct l23 (A[3], B[2], c1[3], c2[2], s2[3], c2[3]);
    BB_struct l32 (A[2], B[3], s2[3], c3[1], prod[5], c3[2]);
    
    BB_struct l33 (A[3], B[3], a, c2[3], prod[6], prod[7]);
    
endmodule
```

Here's my test bench

```
//TestBench
module AM_tb();

reg[3:0] A, B;
wire[7:0] prod;

array_multiplier amtb (A, B, prod);

    initial begin
        $dumpfile("amtb.ved");
        $dumpvars(0, amtb);
        #0  A = 4'b1001; B = 4'b0001;
        #10 A = 4'b1110; B = 4'b1010;
        #10 A = 4'b1111; B = 4'b0000;
        #10 A = 4'b1011; B = 4'b1011;
        
    end
    
    initial begin
        $monitor("%d: A = %b B = %b product = %b ",$time, A, B, prod);  //Display 
    end    

endmodule
```

Output :
I do not know why I am getting 'x' in some positions of the product.

[image: Output]

```
VCD info: dumpfile amtb.ved opened for output.
                   0: A = 1001 B = 0001 product = 00x01001 
                  10: A = 1110 B = 1010 product = 01x01100 
                  20: A = 1111 B = 0000 product = 00x00000 
                  30: A = 1011 B = 1011 product = xxx11001
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a connection error; `c[2]` is undriven.  Change:

```
BB_struct l22 (A[2], B[2], s1[3], c2[1], s2[2], c2[3]);
//                                                 ^
```

to:

```
BB_struct l22 (A[2], B[2], s1[3], c2[1], s2[2], c2[2]);
//                                                 ^
```

This is the output I get after the change:

```
               0: A = 1001 B = 0001 product = 00001001 
              10: A = 1110 B = 1010 product = 01001100 
              20: A = 1111 B = 0000 product = 00000000 
              30: A = 1011 B = 1011 product = 01111001
```

I discovered this error by looking at the waveforms of internal signals.